# character matching in mysql

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do a fuzzy match of company names in MYSQL with PHP for auto-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete)

I have a problem related to character matching in MySQL.

Suppose I have a table which contains a list of names, like elton, angelina, rozy.

If someone queries names like angalina or rosy - where a user can make a spelling mistake - I want to fetch the closest names from the table. What query can be used or what could be the feasible way?

Comment: It looks like you need to use SOUNDEX and Levenshtein distance.  There's a similar question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete