# Is it possible with mySQL to get results when the spelling is not exactly correct

Tags: mysql

Is it possible with mySQL to get results when the spelling is not exactly correct. E.g. a visitor fills out the field with Amstrdam (note that the "e" is missing). Is there a function for mySQL that also shows results similar to Amstrdam:
-Amsterdam
-Amsteldam

Comment: As per your other relation question, this might be what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
expr1 SOUNDS LIKE expr2
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `like` with `%` wildcard:

```
where name like `Amst%`
```

and similar permutations.