# How do I do a levenstein similarity algorithm in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, string, text

Sure, I can write a function for it in Python or something...but how can I do it in MYSQL?

```
WHERE title = "heart of darkness" more or less 3 characters...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar issue was discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete), and [here's a link](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/) from the accepted answer that presents a computation of Levenshtein distance in MYSQL.

Personally, however, I would avoid the stored-procedure approach and just implement it in the driving language (be it Python, PHP or whatever you use to interface the DB).

Comment: Was looking for this answer or similar (dice-coefficient) - if you store the bi-grams in a db table with a key back to the whole text string you wish to search, you can do a simple sql statement like: select count(bigr_ids) hits,search_txt_id from bigram_table where bigram in ('ab','bc','de'...) group by search_txt_id order by hits desc and take advantage of the db indexing to search/sort/match bigrams for you.  This is especially helpful when the list of possible matches grows large (above several thousand).  HTH helps someone else