# Compare a string in java with the data stored in a table column

Tags: java, database, algorithm, search, performance

I have taken a string as input, and need to compare it with a large volume of data from the database. Basically i have to find the distance between the input string and stored strings of the database table

What would be the perfect and efficient solution for this kind of situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of distance do you mean? Levensthein? Which database do you use?

Comment: The distance measured in what?

Comment: yes I used Levensthein distance Algorithm and MySQL as database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete)

Or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search).

Edit: [Here's](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) a function for Levenshtein distance in MySQL.

Edit2: An alternative would be to create an index of the strings you search in using a search engine like Lucene, which also supports Levenshtein distance in its queries.