# How To Check the input for a possible close match from A DB

Tags: php, mysql, regex

OK i will write as clear as possible

it's an e-commerce web site and there is a lot of goods

so i have a searching form that send's the input to a php script via jquery's post

method(ajax) now what i want to do is to check if the input (from the form) is equal

or close to one of the word's in my DB but i cant write a regexp for every single word so is

there a solution ???

for example if the client want to see our offers for pentuim 4 and he wrote peniuom it should tell that "do you mean pentuim"

i hope that i can get an answer now

Comment: exact duplicate of [Using regular expression to search within a database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888374/using-regular-expression-to-search-within-a-database-using-php)

Comment: if it a dupplicate can u please give me an answer ??

Comment: i was the one who asked the first quesion and stil dont get an answer

Comment: i didnt get an answer why not respond me in this question instead of closing it like the other one ???
i am asking here because i really can't find an answer

Comment: I am sorry for this downvoting and closing. Seems to be that your English was not accepted. Please write down more cases: What strings are in the DB, what strings are candidates to be tested. You already mentioned: DB-laptop test-laptoooop. Is it true, that you want to return laptop from the DB if the user searchs for laptooop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just send the user input to a `LIKE` query and get the database to do the search work - they are pretty good at that :-)

If there are no results for an *exact* match then you could pass the search terms through a spell-checker first or use a *fuzzy* search.

[How do I do a fuzzy match of company names in MYSQL with PHP for auto-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete) might also help.

Comment: OK i will write as clear as possible
it's an e-commerce web site and there is a lot of goods so  
i have a searching form that send's the input to a php script via jquery's post method(ajax) 
now what i want to do is to check if the input (from the form) is equal or close to one of the word's in my DB 
but i cant write a regexp for every single word 
so is there a solution ???

Comment: Regex is not the solution here. A _fuzzy_ search or a possibly a _[find as you type](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)_ solution, or combination of both, is the best approach here.