# SSIS fuzzy lookup with MySQL reference table

Tags: mysql, ssis

I am new to SSIS. Both my source and destination database are MySQL 5.5. I was able to set up sample testing ssis package to run between MySql db. Now, I need to put fuzzy look up data flow transformations. My reference table is also belongs to MySQL. So how do I put fuzzy look up with MySQL? Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

The Fuzzy Lookup transformation can only be used with a SQL Server data source. You could stage your MySQL data in a SQL Server database. If that's not possible, this thread lists some alternatives:

[How do I do a fuzzy match of company names in MYSQL with PHP for auto-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following articles very useful for setting up Fuzzy Lookup and Grouping, they are for SQL Server, but I don't think there's any specific that would prevent you from using a MySQL Server as the data store.

- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-fuzzy-lookup-transformations-in-sql-server-integration-services
- http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/06/the-fuzzy-lookup-transformation/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345128.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The process is exactly the same, you will have `source -> fuzzy lookup -> destination` it doesnt matter if the source is SQL, mySQL or text files, the behavior of the fuzzy lookup is the same.

The restriction on SQL Server is on the reference table used on the lookup that must be on SQL Server 2000 or latter

The only task that I'm aware that is restricted to SQl Server is the Data Profiling Task