# MySQL match set of words

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table to store book titles. Whenever I insert a new title I would like to check, if the title already exists. The problem is that, due to typos, an exact match is not possible.

For example

```
'My Dream of Wonder Land'
'My Deam of Wonder Land'
```

So my goal is to create Tags for each title, with every book having at most 3 tags. These tags are the 3 longest words of the title:

```
'My Dream of Wonder Land' = dream, wonder, land
'My Deam of Wonder Land'= deam, wonder, land
```

Now when I add a title, I would like to find all titles, with at least two matching tags. The order of tags should be ignored, meaning that

```
'land, dream, lego'
```

Should match as well.

What would be the best way to store the data in MySQL?

Comment: You could try a fuzzy search to see if the book title exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete

Comment: The problem is that you can have books with the same title. Matching should be done on ISBN numbers or something similar, not on title.

Comment: @fqhv thanks, soundex sounds very promising. But if the order of words change it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [fuzzy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete), as these comparisons can be very complex.

That said, your idea of using tags sounds much more fun.

I would probably have a table just for tags and store them vertically.

```
CREATE TABLE BookTag (
    BookId INT,
    Tag NVARCHAR(50))
```

Then when inserting books you would first calculate the tags and store them in a temp table. I would write a function that gets the n<sup>th</sup> largest word from a string. For this example I'm just going to assume this function exists and is called `nthLargestWord(VARCHAR expression, INT n)`.

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY NewBookTag (Tag)
SELECT nthLargestWord(@booktitle, 1)
UNION
SELECT nthLargestWord(@booktitle, 2)
UNION
SELECT nthLargestWord(@booktitle, 3)
```

You can now join this table to your existing tag's table to see if any have 2 in common.

```
SELECT e.BookId
FROM NewBookTag n
INNER JOIN BookTag e ON n.Tag = e.Tag
GROUP BY e.BookId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

You could just put this in an `IF EXISTS` an insert when it is false.

Also after inserting your book, you already have the tags prepared to insert as well!

```
INSERT INTO Book (BookTitle)
VALUES (@BookTitle)

INSERT INTO BookTag (BookId, Tag)
SELECT b.BookId, t.Tag
FROM Book b
INNER JOIN NewBookTag t ON b.Title = @booktitle
```

This solution allows you to insert one Book at a time, it could be refactored to allow for multiple if need be.